# How to add headers to an outlook interop mail message

Tags: c#, email, outlook, office-interop, email-headers

I am not able to connect my program with an exchange server via smtp. So, I tested with the outlook interop and seems working, at least for sending emails and adding attachments. My problem now is adding the header "disposition-notification-to" to the mail message.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailMessage = application.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem) as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem;

mailMessage.Subject = subject;
mailMessage.Recipients.Add(emailAddress);
mailMessage.HTMLBody = bodyString;
mailMessage.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("urn:schemas:mailheader:disposition-notification-to", notificationAddress);
```

When it come to set the property I get `Exception thrown: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException in program.exe`

I haven't found an example, and most of the time with other libraries like mailkit usually the mail item have an Headers field.

Thanks in advice for any help

Answer (score 0):

To add a custom MIME header on an outgoing message, you need to set a named property in the `PS_INTERNET_HEADERS` namespace (`{00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}`). The code below sets `"X-MyHeader"` MIME header:

```
mailMessage.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/X-MyHeader/0x0000001F", "Custom header value")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a MIME header to the outgoing email by setting a named property in the `PS_INTERNET_HEADERS` namespace using [PropertyAccessor.SetProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.propertyaccessor.setproperty) method:

```
MailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/Your-property-name", "YourValue");
```

On the recipient side you can then read the property on the receiving side by reading the `PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS` (the DASL name is `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001F`) property using the [PropertyAccessor.GetProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.propertyaccessor.getproperty) method.